# How can I detect when the in-app MFMailComposeViewController has disappeared?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have set up some code to pull up MFMailComposeViewController so that users of the app can email people from within the app. How can I detect when this view controller has disappeared?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be useful to you.Here you can know which button he have pressed.So that you can know the mail composer displayed or not

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            //NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            //NSLog(@"Result: saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result" message:@"Mail Sent Successfully" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            //NSLog(@"Result: failed");
            break;
        default:
            //NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
            break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```